# How to setup beeline to use variable in connection string

Tags: hive, hql, apache-zookeeper, beeline

Currently in our dev environment we have hardcoded the beeline connect string to something like

```
     beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://zk0-hi-clu.3qy32mhqlj1ubaea5iyw5joamf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:2181,zk1-hi-clu.3qy32mhqlj1ubaea5iyw5joamf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:2181,zk6-hi-clu.3qy32mhqlj1ubaea5iyw5joamf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2' --hivevar date=20190101 -f test.hql
```

I am trying to see if there are ways we can make the connect dynamic like it will look up a config file like odbc.ini. so when we promote the code to other environment, it will automatically connect to the correct target. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your case: I need some defaults in my shell and use the `alias` functionality of the `bash`.

```
export BEELINE_CONNECTION_STRING='jdbc:hive2://myzookeeper1:2181,myzookeeper2:2181,myzookeeper3:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;'
alias beeline='beeline -u ${BEELINE_CONNECTION_STRING}'
```

After this typing `beeline` causes this:

> beeline
>   Connecting to jdbc:hive2://myzookeeper1:2181,myzookeeper2:2181,myzookeeper3:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;
>   Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292)
>   Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292)
>   Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
>   Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292 by Apache Hive
>   0: jdbc:hive2://myhive>